# Close dropdown when click something else

Tags: jquery-selectbox

How can I close the "selectOptions"? Now I can only close it when clicking "span.selected" or "span.selectArrow". I would like to close it also when clicking another list or just outide the list.

```
function enableSelectBoxes(){
$('div.selectBox').each(function(){
    $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').html());
    $(this).attr('value',$(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').attr('value'));

    $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none'){
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','block');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','none');
        }
    });
    $(this).find('span.selectOption').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('display','none');
        $(this).closest('div.selectBox').attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
        $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
    });
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    //If the user clicks somewhere on the page, but not on the autocomplete.
    if(event.target != $("#autocomplete")[0]) {
        $("#autocomplete").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, thnx it works partly, because I've multiple of these select boxes and it works only with the first one.

Comment: You will have to adapt this code to get it working in your code. You may use a variable which contains the currently opened autocomplete class and use it instead of hardcoding the ID in the code.

Comment: Wherefore is the [0]? and the selector won't work with multiple selectors like: 
        if(event.target !=$('.selected, .selectArrow')[0]){}